# Stuck with conditional statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to add some case statement or IF in my stored procedure but its not returning the right value

I have condition like below

```
IF ((SiteValueCurrentScore <=34)&& ((EECID > 0)|| (dbo.tblVegetationZone.PercentageCleared >70))
     DEVREDFLAG= 0
 Else
     DEVREDFLAG=1
```

I am trying to write the same way in my stored procedure but it gives me a wrong value

```
SELECT dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegetationZoneID, dbo.tblAssessmentCircle.AssessmentCircleID, dbo.tblAssessmentCircle.CircleName, 
    VegetationZoneNumber, VegetationZoneName, VegetationZoneStatusID, VegetationFormationID,
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegTypeID, ConditionID, VegetationZoneArea, 
    COALESCE(EECID,0) AS EECID , 
    COALESCE(dbo.tblVegetationZone.PercentageCleared,0) AS PercentageCleared,
    COALESCE((select CommonName from tblSpecies where SpeciesID=EECID),'not an EEC') as EEC,
    COALESCE(dbo.tblManagementZone.SiteValueCurrentScore,0) AS SiteValueCurrentScore , 
    CASE WHEN SiteValueCurrentScore<=34 and (EECID > 0 OR dbo.tblVegetationZone.PercentageCleared >70) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS DEVREDFLAG,
    RedFlag, MinimumTransectPlot, COALESCE(TransectComplete,0) as TransectComplete, ManagementScoreComplete, dbo.tblVegetationZone.PlantSpeciesMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.OverStoreyCoverMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.OverStoreyCoverMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.MidStoreyCoverMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.MidStoreyCoverMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverGrassesMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverGrassesMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverShrubsMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverShrubsMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverOthersMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.GroundCoverOthersMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.ExoticPlantsCoverMinBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.ExoticPlantsCoverMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.TreesWithHollowsMaxBM, dbo.tblVegetationZone.OverStoreyRegenMaxBM, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.TotalLengthFallenLogsMaxBM,   
    coalesce(dbo.tblVegetationZone.RemoveMultipliers,0) as RemoveMultipliers,
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.DateCreated, dbo.tblVegetationZone.CreatedBySystemUser, 
    dbo.tblVegetationZone.DateUpdated, dbo.tblVegetationZone.UpdatedBySystemUser,
    5 AS SaveType,  dbo.ufn_varbintohexstr(dbo.tblVegetationZone.RowTimestamp) AS RowTimestamp,
    dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode, dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeName, 
    (SELECT Name         FROM dbo.tblClassification    WHERE ClassificationID = VegetationZoneStatusID) AS VegetationZoneStatus,
    (SELECT Name         FROM dbo.tblClassification    WHERE ClassificationID = VegetationFormationID) AS VegetationFormation,
    (SELECT Name         FROM dbo.tblClassification    WHERE ClassificationID = ConditionID) AS Condition,
    (SELECT SubregionName FROM dbo.vwBIMSCMASubregion        WHERE ObjectID =  dbo.tblAssessmentCircle.CMASubregionID) AS CMASubregion
FROM dbo.tblVegetationZone 
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblManagementZone
    ON dbo.tblManagementZone.VegetationZoneID= dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegTypeID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblAssessmentCircle  
    ON dbo.tblVegetationZone.AssessmentCircleID = dbo.tblAssessmentCircle.AssessmentCircleID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblVegetationType
    ON dbo.tblVegetationZone.VegTypeID = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeID 
WHERE dbo.tblAssessmentCircle.AssessmentVersionID
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of data which gives you the wrong `DEVREDFLAG`?

Comment: Can any of `dbo.tblManagementZone.SiteValueCurrentScore`, `EECID` or `dbo.tblVegetationZone.PercentageCleared` be `NULL`?

Comment: yep its possible to be NULL, Oops correct me what's the best approach if i have a null value then ?

Comment: i just used "COALESCE" too in case if its DBNULL

Comment: `COALESCE` would be one way to take `NULL` into account, or you could explicitely check for `NULL` values in your `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(SiteValueCurrentScore,0)<=34 and (EECID > 0 OR COALESCE(dbo.tblVegetationZone.PercentageCleared,0)>70)
  THEN 0
  ELSE 1
END AS DEVREDFLAG
```